# Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root is not an instance of javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx

**I am trying to create my project but facing issue**
**main class**

```
public class Controller extends AnchorPane {

    public Controller() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("is this called");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**FXML File**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="198.0" layoutY="129.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button layoutX="198.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Controller class**

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private Label label;

    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

}
```

Comment: your controller should not implement AnchorPane. The Anchorpane is the root element of your controller, not the controller itself. Accordingly this `fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);` is completely unnecessary

Comment: Also please post the complete stacktrace of your exception

Comment: I have  remove fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);  but still facing issue

Comment: mayybe this tutorial will help you: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm)

Comment: If you use `setRoot`, the root element of the fxml should look like this `<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" xmlns:fx="...`. No idea why there is a `main` method with a call to `launch` in your controller class, but that is almost certainly another issue. The version of the `launch` method you're invoking there (assuming a static import to `Application.launch`) only works from inside a `Application` class. This kind of logic shouldn't be part of the controller anyways.

Comment: [mcve] please ... as @fabian already noted, your setup looks weird: make certain that you post an example that a) follows the usual setup that you find in any tutorial (no fluff for now) and b) demonstrates the problem